# Error creating an eclipse library project for v7 appcompat

Tags: android, installation, android-appcompat

Creating a "library project" in eclipse for the v7 AppCompat I get the following error:

```
[2015-06-02 14:40:27 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
[2015-06-02 14:40:27 - android-support-v7-appcompat] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\jarlist.cache
```

I did it exactly as desribed in [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library), but it won't work.
Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your `Android SDK`, you haven't downloaded the `API Level 19`.

Two solutions as follows:

1. Open your `sdk manager`, install `API Level 19` version platform.
2. Open your `sdk` and take a look what you have installed (ex. you have 22) in your `SDK`, and then modify the project setting to the `SDK platform` you have (22).

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thx, I adjusted project.properties to target=android-22. This helped.

Comment: In my project.properties of both the appcompat v7 library project and my project, the target is `android-22`. I still got this error :-/